# Calculating a Moving Average for 3 months without blank values in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, moving-average, isnullorempty

I have **Client Services** table with **[Billable Minutes]** value.

I need to create **[Moving Average for 3 months]** measure, where the calculation will
only happen - ***if there are values in all 3 months*** in **[Billable Minutes]** exist !
(See below)

If **[Billable Minutes]** value is blank in at least one month in my **Client Services** table, then I want **[Moving Avg]** will show 0 or blank!

My goal:

```
        Client Services table:                              Result:

       Period     [Billable Minutes]                       Period     [Moving Avg]
       2018-11                   200                       2019-01             200  
       2018-12                   300
       2019-01                   100
```

To reach my goal, I am using the following DAX expression for **[Moving Avg 3 months]**:

```
     Moving Avg 3 month = 
      
      VAR PeriodToUse = DATESINPERIOD('Calendar FY'[Date], LASTDATE('Calendar FY'[Date]), -3, MONTH)
      VAR Result = CALCULATE(DIVIDE([Billable Minutes], COUNTROWS ('Calendar FY')), PeriodToUse) 
      VAR  ZeroValue=IF(Minx('Client Services',[Billable Minutes])=0,0,Result)                                
         
         Return Result
```

But, unfortunately, my end result is:

```
        Client Services table:                              Result:

       Period     [Billable Minutes]                       Period     [Moving Avg]
       2018-11                   200                       2018-11             67  
       2018-12                   300                       2018-12            167
       2019-01                   100                       2019-01            200
```

So, it takes an existing values in **Client Services** table and divides them by the number of periods.
For example for 2018-11, 2018-10, 2018-09 - it takes (200+0+0)/3=66.6 (67 rounded)
But I need the **Moving Avg** would be empty for 2018-11, because there are no values for 2018-10, 2018-09 in the Client Services table (same - for 2018-12, should not calculate)

Please, HELP!

**Updated:**

Here is the solution for this (thx to the answer below)
In order to check if there zero in the selected period, extra measures should be created:

```
     Billable Minutes 
     Moving Avg Prev Month = Calculate('Client Services'[Billable Minutes], 
                                        PREVIOUSMONTH('Calendar FY'[Date]))
                       
     Billable Minutes 
    Moving Avg 2nd Prev Month = Calculate
                             ('Client Services'[Billable Minutes Prev Month], 
                                        PREVIOUSMONTH('Calendar FY'[Date]))
```

Then, when you check whether there are zero values - you need to check it - not
just for [Billable Minutes], but for [Billable Minutes] within 3 months period =
within
[Billable Minutes]+[Billable Minutes Prev Month]+
[Billable Minutes 2nd Prev Month]

See the updated below (worked perfect):

```
enter 
     Billable Minutes 3 Months Avg = 

      VAR PeriodToUse = DATESINPERIOD('Calendar FY'[Date], 
                        LASTDATE('Calendar FY'[Date]), -3, MONTH)
      VAR Result = CALCULATE(DIVIDE([Billable Minutes], 
                        COUNTROWS ('Calendar FY')), PeriodToUse)                                                                                                                      
      VAR NMonthsPeriodBlank = 
         if([Billable Minutes] = BLANK(),0,1) + 
         if([Billable Minutes Prev Month] = BLANK(),0,1) + 
         if([Billable Minutes 2nd Prev Month] = BLANK(),0,1)                                       

          RETURN IF(NMonthsPeriodBlank < 3, BLANK(), Result)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these below steps-

**Step-1:** Convert your **Period** column to Date considering 1st date of each month as below-

[image]

**Step-2:** Get back to report by clicking **Close & Apply** and create this below 4 **measures**-

```
total = SUM('Client Services'[Billable Minutes])
```

```
total prev = CALCULATE([total],PREVIOUSMONTH('Client Services'[Period]))
```

```
total second prev = CALCULATE([total prev],PREVIOUSMONTH('Client Services'[Period]))
```

```
3 month avergae = 

VAR devide_by = if([total] = BLANK(),0,1) + if([total prev] = BLANK(),0,1) + if([total second prev] = BLANK(),0,1)
VAR total_amount = [total] + [total prev] + [total second prev]

RETURN IF(
    devide_by < 3,
    BLANK(),
    total_amount/devide_by
)
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

**====================**
**Solution in single measure**
**====================**

You can convert all measures into 1 measure as below-

```
3 month average new = 

VAR this_month = SUM('Client Services'[Billable Minutes])

VAR prev_month = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Client Services'[Billable Minutes]),
    PREVIOUSMONTH('Client Services'[Period])
)

VAR second_prev_month = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Client Services'[Billable Minutes]),
    PREVIOUSMONTH(
        DATEADD(
            'Client Services'[Period],
            -1,
            MONTH
        )
    )
)

VAR devide_by = 
if(this_month = BLANK(),0,1) + 
if(prev_month = BLANK(),0,1) + 
if(second_prev_month = BLANK(),0,1)

VAR total_amount = this_month + prev_month + second_prev_month

RETURN IF(
    devide_by < 3,
    BLANK(),
    total_amount/devide_by
)
```

Comment: Actually, I see your point - let me try tomorrow and I'll post if it worked!

Comment: Thank you, the idea worked! I am going to update my original post - with the modified code.   There is still a slight problem - in case if I need 6 months or 12 months Avg I would need to create 6 or 12 extra measures - for 3rd Prev, 4th Prev, 5th Prev months  etc.   Just wondering if there more elegant way to achieve this.  Will keep researching -  but thx again, your idea helped A LOT!

Comment: @Hell-1931, this is also possible using single measure. I have used separate measure just to show you the idea in clear way, Please check my updated answer with single measure option.

Comment: You can see I have -1 month to get the second previous month. You can add more VAR now and use -2, -3... to go 3rd/4th previous month.

Comment: Thank you - worked, as well; looks better!  But still - if I need it for 6 or 12 months - I would still create VAR - 6, 12 times, etc...   I am wondering if there even easier way  I am almost new to DAX - I'll check it out (and will post here if any luck)

Comment: No more space for wondering :) More period more variable.